# C# Text file upload to a php websever

Tags: c#, php, file, upload, webserver

Okay so there a few examples around, but they are really long winded and confusing

Basically I want to upload a file lets say test.txt from my application to my webserver, i have the PHP to handle the post already,

Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Ive tried using:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

string myFile = @"C:\Draft_3.txt";

client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

client.UploadFile(@"http://myweb.com/projects/idl/Draft Results/RK/myFile", "PUT", myFile);

client.Dispose();
```

but it gives me a "A first chance exception of type `'System.Net.WebException'` occurred in System.dll" runtime error when running that code is there something i am missing?

Comment: check the webexception staus property for return code ("f the method parameter specifies a verb that is not understood by the server or the address resource, the underlying protocol classes determine what occurs. Typically, a WebException is thrown with the Status property set to indicate the error.")

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use the `"POST"` method instead of `"PUT"`? POST is the usual PHP-upload mechanism. PUT is for content management/virtual disk use really. I've never even heard of PHP supporting PUT, because it's usually handled before PHP gets involved; by Apache/httpd.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esst63h0.aspx) that exception is usually caused by one of the following:

> The URI formed by combining BaseAddress, and address is invalid.
>
> -or-
>
> fileName is null, is Empty, contains
>   invalid characters, or does not exist.
>
> -or-
>
> An error occurred while uploading the
>   file.
>
> -or-
>
> There was no response from the server
>   hosting the resource.
>
> -or-
>
> The Content-type header begins with
>   multipart.

I would check the server you are posting to and verify that it's getting the request at all and if it is, what response is it sending.

Comment: i think it might be "The Content-type header begins with multipart."
how would i change this?
I dont get a responce from the server

Comment: if you are debugging locally, you can use http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to watch the communication between your application and the server. I'm not sure about changing the header, you could try using the client.Headers property.